# Can't center container div

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to have a centered grid of buttons that take up the full width, but I can't seem to get the container centered no matter what I try.

Here's the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/a6qo6tzL/

Thanks

```
<div class="Wrapper">
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
<div class="gridButton">
Test
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

CSS

```
.Wrapper {
display:block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
}

.gridButton {
padding: 10px;
background-color: #ff5100;
color: #ffffff;
margin: 5px;
float: left;
width: 250px;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main problem is that your `gridButton` has

```
float: left;
```

Instead, use

```
display: inline-block;
```

Now your buttons can move freely next to one another and be centered. Your wrapper element is already full width but you'll need to tell it to center its content:

```
.Wrapper {
  display:block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

You can get rid of `margin: 0 auto` because that will only affect blocks with a known width.

```css
.Wrapper {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.gridButton {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff5100;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="Wrapper">
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
  <div class="gridButton">
    Test
  </div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got `.Wrapper` set to `100%` width, so even though you have `margin: auto`, the container is full width and will not appear centered. Set it to a constant width at a higher breakpoint:

```
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .Wrapper {
    width: 500px;
  }
}
```

Then consider wrapping your buttons in a columns:

```
.cell {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Here is your updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6qo6tzL/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Use flexbox:

```
.Wrapper {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/67n6jm2u/)

I also replaced the width to [viewport units](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Answer (score 0):

have a look here if this is what you want
https://jsfiddle.net/Raider/744wv0o7/

```
.Wrapper {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
    border:1px solid;
}

.gridButton {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff5100;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px auto;
  /*float: left;*/
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
.Wrapper {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.gridButton {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff5100;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

You where using `float:left;` property which prevents the div's from being centered